# How to get Visual Studio to open Resolve Conflicts window after a TFS Get

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

When I do a Get Latest in Visual Studio, if there are conflicts, there is nothing that is displayed to me to make it obvious. Invariably I think everything is OK, do a build, and often the build works.

The onus is always on me to remember to look for conflicts, to open the Conflicts window.
Is there any way to make VS get in my face, and tell me that there is now a conflict?

Comment: VS should raise the conflicts window when you have unresolved conflicts.  Why do you think you have them?  Can you add a screenshot or two that illustrate this process?

Comment: Hi, Please consider marking DaveShaw's answer as the correct answer. This is a good question, and that does answer it.

Comment: Sorry I never followed up on this. I didn't recall getting email reminders. Besides which, the problem seemed to go away on its own.  I wouldn't mark DaveShaw's answer as correct since that tells you how to manually open the window. My questions was why it doesn't open on its own after a 'get latest' that has conflicts. But like I said the problem went away and that window does pop up when I have conflicts -- even if it started out as closed. Thanks all for answering.

Comment: @valerie Does the resolve conflicts window open each time you open VS, even if you've explicitly closed it in the previous session, any time conflicts exist? I can only get it to reappear by following DaveShaw's advice.

Comment: Yes. I always close the conflicts window after I've resolved the conflicts. The next time I have a conflict- whether I've closed VS or not - that conflict window opens again. Not sure why it now works. I have VS 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I have the same issue and actually what happens is that the Resolve Conflicts window will always hide in the Well (drop-down list of tabs that can't fit in the horizontal list of open tabs). So when you have fewer tabs, it stays open (focused tab) but otherwise it seems to simply disappear (which is down the Well list).

Answer (score 126):

You can re open the Resolve Conflicts window if you closed it by mistake from Team Explorer. Goto: Pending Changes, then from the Actions drop down, select Resolve Conflicts.

From there you can click Get All Conflicts.

Normally VS will prompt you to resolve any conflicts as soon as you do one of the following:

- Get latest
- Check in
- Merge

Comment: Or just restart VS and it will appear again

Answer (score 85):

Click the link I surrounded with a red contour in the Team Explorer pane.

[image]

And in Visual Studio 2013:

[image]

Comment: @Matthew Lock: Are you sure in Visual Studio 2013 the reason for the Resolve Conflicts operation to be inside the dropdown as an entry is VS 2013 itself and not due to the Team Explorer to not be wide enough?

Comment: yes, even if you make the pane huge it still resides in the drop down https://i.imgur.com/MDpesjJ.png

Comment: @MatthewLock: You've shown an example when there is no conflict occurring. Are you sure it happens also when there is a conflict ongoing?

Answer (score -7):

If you're coding in C# then on your Visual Studios editor, select the Tools menu, then the options submenu.

A dialog will pop up.  From there select Text Editor, then select C#, then select Advanced.

Then check the box for Show live semantic errors.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question !

Comment: this is something else